# flutter build apk --split-per-abi doesnt create three APK files

Tags: flutter, dart, apk

after running command in terminal, Gradle is completed unreasonably quick with a successful build result only for app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk, however, when checking the flutter-apk folder I see that only the files bellow were built and had their time stamp updated

app-debug.apk,

app.apk,

app.apk.sha1

but other files were not changed and still had an old time stamp (two weeks ago)

app-arm64-v8a-release.apk,

app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk,

app-x86_64-release.apk

```
• output message of flutter build apk --split-per-abi command
============================================================
Project_Path> flutter build apk --split-per-abi

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      12.5s

√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (7.8MB).


• steps taken so far
=============================
run flutter doctor 
•• No issues found!

run flutter clean 
•• 
Deleting build...                                                  863ms

Deleting .dart_tool...                                               6ms

Deleting .packages...                                                0ms

Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                       0ms

Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...                            0ms

Deleting .flutter-plugins-dependencies...                            0ms

Deleting .flutter-plugins...                                         0ms
```

[image]
OUTPUT APK FILES

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the contents of `build/app/outputs/apk` then retry the commands.

Comment: Hi, 

Removed the content of aforementioned directory,
it did not help however I realised what was wrong; as this project was a copy of another - the Project Path was of the previous project.
once corrected I was able to run the command and get the files. 
they are all updating and time stamp is now good but the output message of the flutter build apk command is still showing only for 
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (7.8MB).


but at least now I have access to these files.
Thanks.